# How can I understand these two equations about the indirect measurement?

Tags: measurement, decoherence, linear-algebra

I'm reading an article about environmental monitoring and information transfer. Suppose $S$ represents a quantum system and $E$ is the environment. Assume at time $t=0$ there are no correlations between $S$ and $E$: $\rho_{SE}(0)=\rho_{S}(0)\otimes\rho_{E}(0)$, and this composite density operator evolved under the action of $U(t) = e^{-iHt/h}$, where $H$ is the total Hamiltonian. Let $P_\alpha$ be a projective operator on $E$. Then, the probability of obtaining outcome $α$ in this measurement when $S$ is described by the density operator $\rho_s(t)$ is given as

$$
\text{Prob}(\alpha|\rho_s(t))=\text{Tr}_E (P_αρ_E(t))
$$

and the density matrix of $S$ conditioned on the particular outcome $\alpha$ is

$$
\rho_s^{\alpha}(t)= \frac{\text{Tr}_E\{(I\otimes P_\alpha)\rho_{SE}(t)(I\otimes P_\alpha)\}}{\text{Prob}(\alpha|\rho_s(t))}
$$

I'm wondering how those two equations coming from? Also, since the indirect measurement aims to yield information about S without performing a projective (and thus destructive) direct measurement on S, why there's $P_\alpha$ in the equation? Thanks!!

Comment: I think there is a typo in the equation for $\text{Prob}(\alpha|\rho_s(t))$: don't you mean $\rho_{SE}(t)$ in place of $\rho_E(t)$?

Comment: The two equations - for outcome probability and post-measurement state - are density matrix variants of the equations in [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15563/what-does-m-m-psi-i-rangle-mean-in-the-equation-pmi-langle-psi-im-m-d). They are also equations $(2.159)$ and $(2.160)$ in Mike & Ike with the caveat about subsystems described in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15606/where-does-the-term-psi-rangle-langle-psi-come-from-while-calculating-the-e/15607#15607).

Comment: @Adam Zalcman Thanks for the comment! No it's not a typo. The two equations come from eqn 13&14 in the Quantum Decoherence paper: doi.org/10.1016/j.physrep.2019.10.001

Comment: You're right. I'm not sure why I thought otherwise. Perhaps I missed the fact that $P_\alpha$ are projectors on $E$ which is implicit in the use of partial trace and tensor product. I made a small change to your question to clarify this. Anyway, do the pointers to the [other question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15563/what-does-m-m-psi-i-rangle-mean-in-the-equation-pmi-langle-psi-im-m-d) and section 2.4.2 in Mike&Ike help you or is there something else that's not clear? :-)

Comment: @Adam Zalcman Thank you so much!! I noticed the analogy, but I'm still wondering why the denominator doesn't have the square root in this case, and what's the meaning of two $I\otimes P_\alpha$.

Comment: Regarding square root: A density matrix is a convex combination of outer products like $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$. After state collapse you need to renormalize both the bra and the ket, so there are two square roots in the denominator that are multiplied.

Comment: Regarding the two $I\otimes P_\alpha$: the identities can be written implicitly or explicitly. Both forms have the same meaning, see [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15606/where-does-the-term-psi-rangle-langle-psi-come-from-while-calculating-the-e/15607#15607).

Comment: @Adam Zalcman Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two equations are part of the measurement postulate of quantum mechanics which states that probability of the outcome $m$ in a measurement described by operators $M_m$ on a state $\rho$ is

$$
p(m) = \mathrm{tr}(M_m^\dagger M_m \rho)\tag1
$$

(c.f. $(2.159)$ in Nielsen & Chuang) and the post-measurement state is

$$
\frac{M_m\rho M_m^\dagger}{\mathrm{tr}(M_m^\dagger M_m \rho)}\tag2
$$

(c.f. $(2.160)$ in Nielsen & Chuang).

---

The first equation in the question follows from substitutions

$$
m = \alpha \\
\rho = \rho_E(t) \\
M_m = P_\alpha
$$

in $(1)$. The second follows from substitutions

$$
\rho = \rho_{SE}(t) \\
M_m = I\otimes P_\alpha
$$

followed by partial trace over the environment on the post-measurement state.